# Novice working through a Stroustrup book, need advice

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to accept the input of a measurement followed by the unit (ex. "10cm"), convert it to meters, and then store it if it is the largest or smallest value yet. Then, it should add it to a sum of all values entered before termination with "|". It should finally output the largest, smallest, and the sum. HALP! Not homework - just trying to teach myself.

Edit: Apologies for lack of clarity -

I have now discovered that I simply needed to add a whitespace between the measurement and unit input. My question then becomes: would it be possible to (without extravagant knowledge that a chapter 4 novice couldn't possess) accept "10cm" and get the same result as inputting "10 cm"? The book specifically says:

"add a unit to each do double entered ; that is, enter values such as 10cm, 2.5in, 5ft, or 3.33m"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double n1 = 0;
    string unit = " ";
    double largest = 0;
    double smallest = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double inM = 0;

  while(cin >> n1 >> unit)
  {    
    if(unit == "m")
        inM = n1;
    else if(unit == "cm")
        inM = n1 / 100;
    else if(unit == "in")
        inM = (n1 * 2.54) / 100;
    else if(unit == "ft")
        inM = ((n1 / 12) * 2.54) / 100;
    else
    {
        cout << "dont understand";
        break;
    }

    if(inM > largest && smallest == 0){
        largest = inM;
        smallest = inM;
    }
    else if (inM < smallest)
        smallest = inM;
    else if (inM > largest)
        largest = inM;

    sum += inM;            
  }
  cout << "The smallest value you entered was: " << smallest << "\nThe largest value you entered was: " << largest << "\nThe sum of all values was: " << sum; 
}
```

Comment: This one is probably best answered on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: @Lstor if I enter in "10cm" it skips the body of the while loop and outputs "The smallest value you entered was: 0
The largest value you entered was: 0
The sum of all values was: 0"

Comment: @IronSavior sorry new to the site and everything's proper place - what type of material goes on the main site and what should go on Programmers?

Comment: @VincentRodomista I'm not getting any problems? 

`10cm
|
The smallest value you entered was: 0.1
The largest value you entered was: 0.1
The sum of all values was: 0.1`

Comment: @VincentRodomista You can ask for help with specific programming problems here, and I think this question is on-topic for StackOverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information about what is on-topic for SO. However, your question could be a bit more clear. I suggest you update your question with information about what your problem is, and what you are looking for.

Comment: @VincentRodomista Try putting a space after 10, so you get "10 cm", and then input that. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/, that /should/ work...

Comment: The biggest problem I see is that you're trying to convert from feet to inches by dividing by 12 (should multiply instead). Since it's all floating point math, I'd personally use floating point for all your constants as well (e.g., `100.0`, `12.0` instead of `100` and `12`).

Comment: @AStupidNoob it should still work without the whitespace. The `>>` extraction will get all the characters that can be treated as part of a double -- it will stop when it reachs a char.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting "don't understand"?

Comment: @n.m. I'm not getting "don't understand". When I pop in "10cm" it simply skips the body entirely.

Comment: Can you enter any other unit? What compiler and OS are you using?

Comment: The program parses `10cm` just fine for me.

Comment: @n.m. using xCode on OSX

Comment: @n.m. also, any other unit (when entered without a whitespace) has the same problem

Comment: If it works with a whitespace and doesn't work without one, then I'd say your standard library is broken.